# Problema con Certificado SSL Lets Encrypt

Tags: wordpress, certificado-ssl, digitalocean

Que tal compañeros he activado un certificado SSL siguiendo este enlace:

https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/using-lets-encrypt-ssl-with-your-wordpress-project--cms-22303

Todo bien se pudo instalar pero al momento de hacer refresh a mi página aparece el https tachado en rojo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice una prueba con https://www.ssllabs.com y me aparece que todo esta bien.

Es un WordPress que esta alojado en DigitalOcean con Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: puede ser cache, por las dudas fijate en clickando en certificate a nombre de quien está o si falta alguna cosa. para limpiar el ssl state en chrome -> https://serverfault.com/questions/279984/how-do-i-clear-chromes-ssl-cache#comment1105465_688828 .  El score sslabs es B o mejor?

Comment: Que tal @aloMalbarez gracias por responder, he borrado caché y en la información del certificate no me aparece nada, la prueba en ssllabs es de A

Comment: fijate que edité el comentario con el enlace a varias formas de limpiarlo cuando se pone terco

Comment: Gracias le he dado una leída y he buscado el directorio en el servidor donde tengo alojado wordpress y active el certificado pero no lo encuentro. Igual seguiré buscando, para ver si doy con el

Comment: ¿Has enlazado el fichero del certificado a la sección de SSL de tu servidor?